# creating a list of dictionaries from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This is my df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sym': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'q', 'w', 'e'],
                   'sym_t': ['tsla', 'msft', 'f', 'aapl', 'aa', 'gg', 'amd', 'ba', 'c']})
```

I want to separate this df into groups of three and create a list of dictionaries:

```
options = [{'value':'a b c', 'label':'tsla msft f'}, {'value':'x y z', 'label':'aapl aa gg'}, {'value':'q w e', 'label':'amd ba c'}]
```

How can I create that list? My original df has over 1000 rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `groupby` to concatenate the rows, then `to_dict`:

```
tmp = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//3).agg(' '.join)
tmp.columns = ['value', 'label']
tmp.to_dict(orient='records')
```

Output:

```
[{'value': 'a b c', 'label': 'tsla msft f'},
 {'value': 'x y z', 'label': 'aapl aa gg'},
 {'value': 'q w e', 'label': 'amd ba c'}]
```